# Swift How to customize a inner navigationController's navigationItem which embedded in another main navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am working on a swift ios project with this hierarchy:
Main Nav -> TabBar Controller -> inner Nav -> viewController 1.

My question is how to customize inner nav title view, I have tried several soultions but it all tend to show the Main Nav's title view. Does it mean the inner Nav title view has been overlapped by the main Nav?  Can anyone help me figure it out? Thanks is advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your storyboard screenshot?

Comment: @NiravD Hey, thanks for your reply. I have uploaded my storyboard, please check it :)

Comment: Is `tabbarController` your initial screen? Means app launch it is the first screen?

Comment: @NiravD The initial screen is the mainNav and the tab is embedded with Tab controller.

Comment: That is the problem instead of that Set tabarController as Initial screen and embed your all Tabbar item to the individual navigationController. That will solved your problem.

Comment: Is it works for you after creating individual navigationController for all tabbar item and setting tabbarController as initial screen?

Comment: @NiravD Yes, it works. Thanks for your help.